# list of lists of anagram in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, anagram

If my input is a list like this:

```
words = ['cat','act','wer','erw']
```

I want to make a list of lists of anagrams like this -

```
[['cat','act'],['wer','erw']]
```

I have tried to do something like this:

```
[[w1 for w in words if w!=w1 and sorted(w1)==sorted(w)] for w1 in words]
```

but it doesn't work. The output was :

```
[['cat'], ['act'], ['wer'], ['erw']]
```

In addition, I don`t want to use any import (except string). What is the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that your original method is actually O(#words<sup>2</sup>) time and thus will not work on large datasets of perhaps more than 10000 words.

---

**groupby one-liner:**

One of the most <strike>elegant</strike> weirdest use cases I've ever seen for `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(words,key=sorted),sorted)]
[['cat', 'act'], ['wer', 'erw']]
```

---

**defaultdict three-liner:**

Using `collections.defaultdict`, you can do:

```
anagrams = defaultdict(list)
for w in words:
    anagrams[tuple(sorted(w))].append(w)
```

As for If doing it your original way without any imports, you can emulate `collections.defaultdict` as follows:

```
anagrams = {}
for w in words:
    key = tuple(sorted(w))
    anagrams.setdefault(key,[]).append(w)
```

example:

```
>>> anagrams
{('e', 'r', 'w'): ['wer', 'erw'], ('a', 'c', 't'): ['cat', 'act']}
```

(Also written up in [whi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860616/list-of-lists-of-anagram-in-python/10860894#10860894).)

---

**map-reduce:**

This problem is also the poster child for map-reduce, where the reduction key you use is the sorted letters (or more efficiently, a hash). This will allow you to massively parallelize the problem.

---

If we assume the length of words is bounded, the `groupby` solution is `O(#words log(#words))`, while the hash solution is expected `O(#words)`. In the unlikely event the length of words is arbitrary in length, sorting (`O(length log(length))` per word) is less efficient than using an order-agnostic hash of the letters (`O(length)` per word). Sadly, collections.Counter is not hashable so you'd have to write your own.

Comment: Elegant and concise, but unfortunately the OP said without using any import

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood: ah, missed that; think I'll leave this here for future reference though.

Comment: Yes leave it here - it is a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
words = ['cat','act','wer','erw']
dic={}
for w in words:
    k=''.join(sorted(w))
    dic.setdefault(k,[])
    dic[k].append(w)
print dic.values()
```

this is better in perform:  O(n)

Comment: Slightly more eficient to write `dic.setdefault(k,[]).append(w)` - saves looking the key up twice in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can find various solutions to anagrams of a single word at a time by googleing. It is likely that there would be a more efficient solver around than the obvious "search through all the words I know and see if they have the same letters".

Once you have one, you can put it into a function:

```
def anagrams(word):
    "return a list of all known anagrams of *word*"
```

Once you have that, generalising it to a list of words is trivial:

```
[anagrams(word) for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the trick in the style you prefer

```
[[w, w1] for w1 in words for w in words if w!=w1 and sorted(w1)==sorted(w)][::2]
```

Comment: This is O(len(words)**2) so if there are lots of words this will be very slow. You've nested `for w1 in words` in `for w in words`.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood you are right, this is not a fast solution, but it's "pythonic" :)

Comment: and what [::2] means in your sulotion

Comment: @EyalDreifuss [::2] means from the first element, take every second element

Comment: @EyalDreifuss for your answer, this part `[w1 for w in words if w!=w1 and sorted(w1)==sorted(w)]` only gets each single element and makes each of them a list; even for that case, it should be `w` instead of `w1` at the beginning, otherwise you are just taking the `w1` from the outside loop